# What does the * CSS operator do? Are there any other CSS operators?

Tags: css, operators, css-selectors

While studying how to build a nested table from list elements in CSS, I stumbled across this page: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/horizontal01.htm.

I noticed that the stylesheet uses a few symbols I'm not familiar with in CSS, namely the `>` and `*` symbols as what seem to be some kind of CSS operators.

For example:

```css
ul#navlist li * a:link, ul#navlist li * a:visited
```

I was able to Google and find out that `>` simply indicates a parent/child relationship between two elements, but I still have no idea what `*` does. I'm also curious to know whether or not there are other “operators” like these, and if so, could somebody direct me to a reference of all of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` is the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector). It selects any element.

However, it's a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors), and as such it doesn't belong in the same family as what are called [combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) (which indicate relationships between two elements). `>` is the child combinator, which as you say defines a parent-child relationship between two elements.

The spaces between `ul#navlist` and `li`, `li` and `*`, etc are all descendant combinators. Unlike `>`, the space doesn't indicate a parent-child relationship; it just asks for an element that's contained somewhere within, whether it's a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc, but not a sibling.

The *difference* between these two selectors (from your link):

```css
ul#navlist li > a:link, ul#navlist li > a:visited
ul#navlist li * a:link, ul#navlist li * a:visited
```

Is that the first one with `>` asks for `a:link` and `a:visited` elements
that sit directly within `ul#navlist li` elements,

while the second one with `*` asks for `a:link` and `a:visited` elements
that sit within **any element that's within `ul#navlist li`**.
In other words, `a:link, a:visited` that's **not directly** within `ul#navlist li`.

Comment: The links given are all part of the CSS3 selectors spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors

Comment: Actually, now that I look at them again, those selectors seem misleading. I'd want to use `ul#navlist > li a` instead of `ul#navlist li > a`. But if the stylesheet works anyway...