# what does *margin-top imply in css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does an asterisk do in a CSS property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563651/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-property-name)

I'm going through css style sheet provided with [twitter bootstrap 2.0](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/) and I see a lot of properties for which a * is appended before them. Ex: *margin-top , *zoom, *display etc..

What does this * imply ? Ex: listing of one of the rules -

```
audio, canvas, video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

[direct link for bootstrap.css file](http://pastebin.com/s8CGCJUR)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202290/what-does-the-css-operator-do-are-there-any-other-css-operators

Comment: @J...: That's for selectors, not properties.

Comment: @J...: a * as part of a selector seems fine but this * is next to the property it self.. editing the question to directly paste the whole rule...

Comment: @BoltClock - ah, of course.  It's early, I should have read more closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a CSS hack. Its intent is to target specific versions of IE:

The `*<property>` is used to target IE7 (and below).

This [aticle](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/) for NetTuts explains it well